# XCode - my project is empty after I restart my Mac

Tags: xcode, bitbucket

I got this very weird problems these days on `XCode (8.3.2 8E2002)`:

My `XCode` project is working well with `Bitbucket` source control. Some days ago, after booting up my Mac, all files in my project are gone, its project folder name became `<myprojectname> (1)`. Then I cloned it from `Bitbucket` and was able to work on it, committed, ... 
I find that every time I restart my machine, the symptom comes back and I have to redo cloning from `Bitbucket`, work, commit, ...

Previous XCode versions never had this kind of issue before. Has anyone got it? What's wrong with my `XCode`/`Bitbucket`? How can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: I am using `Google Drive` as a tool to back up my data, and I am working directly in the `Google Drive` folder. I notice every time I boot up my machine without `Google Drive` (I disabled it), all are ok: my code is still there, `<myprojectname> (1)` is not created. And things just happen when my MAC boots with `Google Drive`! I have other 2 projects: if I start my MAC with `Google Drive`, then all files in those 2 projects marked as `A` and I have to do some extra steps in order to recover them; if I don't, things are perfect. Is there a chance `Google Drive` corrupt my `git` files?

Comment: I really suspect `Google Drive`. I can replicate this issue pretty easily. I had used `Dropbox` before but never got this issue. Has anyone got this issue?